# How can i copy a row in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, copy-paste

i am using C# with framework 4.0 and SQL server 2008 R2.
my program works fine with a small data, but when the data become huge i got timeout Exception.
i have tried with:

```
public void CreateSqlCommand()
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
}
```

but it still hang up, i got Insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query, the question is not how to increase the time out, but how can i optimized my programme.

i got 6 table LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A, LS_CLIENT_INSEE_B, etc with conatain only 2 column
[image]

the objective is simple, i just want to copy the existing row but with different NO_CLIENT.

```
     public void CopyInsee(string SourceClient, List<object> DestClient)
             {
                 List<object> List_A = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_B = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_B", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_C = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_C", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_D = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_D", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_P = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_P", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N1 = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N1", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N2 = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N2", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N3 = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N3", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N4 = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N4", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N5 = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N5", SourceClient);
                 List<object> List_N6 = oClInse.GetInseClient("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N6", SourceClient);

                 foreach (var oItem in DestClient)
                 {
                     if (List_A.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A", oItem.ToString(), List_A);
                     if (List_B.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_B", oItem.ToString(), List_B);
                     if (List_C.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_C", oItem.ToString(), List_C);
                     if (List_D.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_D", oItem.ToString(), List_D);
                     if (List_N.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N", oItem.ToString(), List_N);
                     if (List_P.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_P", oItem.ToString(), List_P);
                     if (List_N1.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N1", oItem.ToString(), List_N1);
                     if (List_N2.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N2", oItem.ToString(), List_N2);
                     if (List_N3.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N3", oItem.ToString(), List_N3);
                     if (List_N4.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N4", oItem.ToString(), List_N4);
                     if (List_N5.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N5", oItem.ToString(), List_N5);
                     if (List_N6.Count != 0) oClInse.RempliClientInse("LS_CLIENT_INSEE_N6", oItem.ToString(), List_N6);
                 }

             }

 public List<object> GetInseClient(string NomTable,  string IdClient)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
                {
                    var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();
                    string sql_SelectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + NomTable + " WHERE NO_CLIENT = @NO_CLIENT";
                    SqlCommand comm_SelectAll = new SqlCommand(sql_SelectAll, connectionWrapper.conn);
                    comm_SelectAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO_CLIENT", IdClient);
                    List<object> oList = new List<object>();
                    SqlDataReader readerOne = comm_SelectAll.ExecuteReader();
                    while (readerOne.Read())
                    {
                        oList.Add(readerOne["NO_INSEE"].ToString());
                    }
                    readerOne.Close();
                    readerOne.Dispose();
                    return oList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                if (!excThrown.Message.StartsWith("Err_")) { throw new Exception("Err_GetAllUsrClient", excThrown); }
                else { throw new Exception(excThrown.Message, excThrown); }
            }

        }

public void RempliClientInse(string NomTable, string IdClient, List<object> InseList)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
                {
                    var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();

                    string sSql = "";

                    foreach (var oItem in InseList)
                    {
                        if (sSql != "") sSql += " UNION ALL ";
                        sSql += "SELECT '" + oItem.ToString() + "', '" + IdClient + "'";
                    }   
                    string TempSqlInst = "INSERT INTO " + NomTable + "  ( NO_INSEE, NO_CLIENT )  " + sSql;

                        SqlCommand comm_InsertMod = new SqlCommand(TempSqlInst , connectionWrapper.conn);
                        comm_InsertMod.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        comm_InsertMod.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                if (!excThrown.Message.StartsWith("Err_")) { throw new Exception("Err_Domaine_RempliInsee", excThrown); }
                else { throw new Exception(excThrown.Message, excThrown); }
            }            
        }
```

so maybe instead of SELECT first then INSERT INTO, i can do both in the same time, to avoid TimeOutException and Memory insuffisante probleme.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pure sql for that. Create stored procedure in SQL data base add it to your linq 2 sql project and execute it from the c# code.

Comment: Thanks you for responding, could you give me a hint with cursor or just INSERT SELECT INTO

Comment: just a simple code you can use: `insert into dbo.LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A 
select a.NO_INSEE, 'C002' from dbo.LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A as a where a.NO_CLIENT = 'C001'` Here C001 is source client id and C002 is destination client id.